# Running a file within nested directory

Tags: python, module

My code structure is as follows:

```
Main Code
   Directory 1
      file1.py
      file2.py
      ...
   Directory 2
     x.py
     y.py
   Directory 3
     main_script.py
```

In main script.py we have the following imports

```
from MainCode.Directory2.x import *
```

When I execute this code,I get the error: `No module named MainCode`

Any ideas on how to fix these kind of errors.I am assuming that this knowledge will be useful as I develop bigger packages and I can't have all my files living in one directory.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/9050514

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: You need `__init__.py` in the folders you are importing from

Comment: tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder didn't help.@Chase how does __init__.py help ,does that help the compiler in distinguishing between relative and absolute imports?

Comment: Actually,the actual directory structure is as follows.And yes every file has __init__.py file in it.
DeepRL2019
CS285

Agents
  __init__.py
 base_agent.py
 bc_agent.py
pg_agent.py
Infrastructure
  logger.py,rl_trainer.py,tf_utils.py,utils.py,__init__.py
Policies
Example of import 
from cs285.infrastructure.utils import *

Comment: did you tried giving a space between main and code as in your question line 2

Comment: probably it is related to how you running your script from which directory, run it from the parent directory of Mainfolder

Comment: @SparshGarg did you tried all the answers in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Comment: @deadshot yes I did,__init__.py,export ,import sys(and its variations)